# Webserver fails to start due to missing bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to start a simple spring application

I have the main.java file right here:

```
    package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here are the libs that I have:
[image]

Here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

And finally the error is this one:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

[2014-02-15 11:14:25.385] - 6116 INFO [main] --- main.Main: Starting Main on Vlad-PC with PID 6116 (C:\Users\Vlad\IdeaProjects\blog\target\classes started by Vlad)
[2014-02-15 11:14:25.473] - 6116 INFO [main] --- org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2ca76650: startup date [Sat Feb 15 11:14:25 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[2014-02-15 11:14:25.579] - 6116 INFO [main] --- org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener: Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/IdeaProjects/blog/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/IdeaProjects/blog/lib/com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.api-7.0.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/IdeaProjects/blog/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201103241009.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/Vlad/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Community%20Edition%2013.0.2/lib/idea_rt.jar]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:616)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:877)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:866)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    ... 12 more
```

From what I can understand I'm missing a bean? However it looks as if I do have the jar spring beans.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring boot try to start a web server, but did not findy any in the class path. Try to add this dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>I Dont know</version
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

Btw you pom does not look like a typical spring boot pom! Compare it with http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/README.html

Comment: Another BTW: your `Main` class is not used in the app (I think you probably put `Application.class` in the main method by mistake).

Comment: @DaveSyer oh god. Please do tell me that the name of the file must not be Application.java

Comment: Why would you think that? You have `Application.class` in your `SpringApplication` is all.

Comment: compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf") I was facing issue by not including this dependency

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are differences depending on the version.

org.springframework -> Please correct to a higher version. :)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For example, a org.springframework.boot 1.2.3.RELEASE, error was always when it is org.springframework 4.1.4.RELEASE below version.

In the case of more than org.springframework 4.1.5.RELEASE, I worked without error.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error now and I solved it by just including the same versions of the Spring packages in my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.6.RELEASE'
    }

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
```

For example, if you changed one of the packages and you add on a version number to override the static value of 1.1.6.RELEASE, then the error will be displayed:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.6.RELEASE'
    }

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:1.2.5.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but I might just save someone hours of agony looking for the solution.I had that same problem while setting up a spring-boot project.

I had this in my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-
web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', 
version: '5.0.2.RELEASE'// <--- Source of my problems
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-
security-oauth2', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-
datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.3'
testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.196'
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: 
'5.2.12.Final'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.6-jre'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-
data-jpa', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-
starter-test', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
```

This is a spring-boot project and so, it will do a lot of configuration for you

That said, you do not need some the many dependencies you would have to put if it was a spring project. The **boot-starter** dependencies are enough.