# Spring Boot Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am currently writing an API backend using Spring which I want to deploy on to a production server using Spring Boot.

If I run the backend in Eclipse compiling to a war (specified in Maven), and using Tomcat 7, it runs without a problem.

However as I want to deploy to the server I am using Spring Boot.

Application.java

```
package com.ninjasquare.server;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

            System.out.println("NinjaSquare server up and running with Spring Boot!");

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ninjasquare</groupId>
    <artifactId>NinjaSquareServer</artifactId>
    <!-- Server Deployment Change Required: 1. Change war to jar -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Spring Boot related config -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <!-- Note: By default Spring Boot uses Tomcat 8. We set this so we can use Tomcat 7. -->
    <!-- <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version> -->
    <!-- <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> -->

    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <jersey.version>1.8</jersey.version>
    <org.springframework.data.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
    <org.springframework.spring-test>2.5</org.springframework.spring-test>
    <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <javax.servlet.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
    <javax.servlet.jsp.version>2.1</javax.servlet.jsp.version>
    <javax.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</javax.servlet.jstl.version>

    <spring-social-facebook-version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring-social-facebook-version>

    <junit.version>4.4</junit.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    <org.hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <com.github.jsimone.version>7.0.22.3</com.github.jsimone.version>
    <org.neo4j.app.version>1.8.2</org.neo4j.app.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.9</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.version>2.5.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.version>
    <org.codehaus.mojo>1.2.1</org.codehaus.mojo>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin>2.4</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-surefire-plugin>2.6</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-surefire-plugin>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Server Deployment Change Required: 2. Include our custom JAR. For now, patch this code on the server manually.
    Note: This JAR needs to be installed with maven install:install-file on the server -->
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ninjasquare.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>ninjasquarecommon</artifactId>
        <version>0.01</version>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <!--  Spring Boot dependency -->

    <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Was this code missing before? -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson/Jersey deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SDN -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.springframework.data.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.springframework.spring-test}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.springframework-version}</version> -->
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.springframework-version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version> -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${javax.servlet.jstl.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!--  Import Spring Social libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${spring-social-facebook-version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- additional libraries required by neo/spring... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${junit.version}</version> -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>


    <!-- execute immediately support... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${com.github.jsimone.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${org.neo4j.app.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        <version>${org.neo4j.app.version}</version>
    </dependency>

            <!--        
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Plugin for Spring Boot Maven -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version> -->
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.version}</version> -->
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${org.codehaus.mojo}</version> -->
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- enable execution environment... -->
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>${com.github.jsimone.version}</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> -->

        <!-- get Spring, Maven & JUnit test working... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-surefire-plugin}</version> -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/testcases/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I copy the whole project over to my linux server, and I run **maven package**, the code compiles without a problem. When I then run the generated jar file with **java -jar [name of file]** I get the following error:

```
09:17:26.946 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ninjasquare.server.Application.main(Application.java:13) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner$Tomcat8TldSkipSetter.setSkipPattern(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:106) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.setPatternToTomcat8SkipFilter(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:61) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.<init>(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:56) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.apply(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:87) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:154) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I think the issue is because I don't have the right versions of Spring/Spring Boot running (perhaps it's trying to use an incorrect version of Tomcat so the method doesn't exist?)

**Update 2015-04-06:** I tried kucing_terbang's suggestion of using spring boot v1.1.10 but now get the error as follows:

```
[Stacktrace deleted, as out of space for stackoverflow question, refer to stacktrace of v1.1.12.RELEASE below]
```

**Update 2015-04-07:** I then tried with v1.1.12.RELEASE which gave similar errors:

```
07:41:29.917 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
07:41:29.949 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) ~[spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at com.ninjasquare.server.Application.main(Application.java:13) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted

07:41:29.952 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) ~[spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) ~[spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at com.ninjasquare.server.Application.main(Application.java:13) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [NinjaSquareServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174) ~[spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) ~[spring-boot-1.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.12.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I then tried a mvn clean and mvn package again, which gave me the following error on compile:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[6,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpringBootApplication
  location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[6,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpringBootApplication
  location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[INFO] 4 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.839s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 07 07:31:41 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project NinjaSquareServer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[6,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[6,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
[ERROR] /home/dengke/test_garden/NinjaSquareServer-DS-ServerDeploymentPOC-2015-04-04/src/main/java/com/ninjasquare/server/Application.java:[9,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class SpringBootApplication
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

However if I using v1.2.3.RELEASE I don't get the compile error, and if I then change to v1.1.12.RELEASE and run mvn package without a clean, I don't get the error either (but I get the error when running the jar as before).

Perhaps this is indicative of a deeper issue?

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you have commented out the section of your pom where you set the tomcat version to 7, are you aware of that?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, but I am aware! I get a different error when I use Tomcat 7, so I thought that perhaps just letting Spring use a later version was the right thing to do. If I comment back in the line for Tomcat 7, I get the following error instead:

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.addApplicationListener(org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener)

Comment: On a side note, I also commented out a lot of the <version> tags in the dependencies, as Eclipse was telling me they were overriding the versions already specified by spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: @DengkeSha well, you're right on the incorrect version of tomcat as in the stack trace, you can see that it trying to get the tomcat 8 function instead of tomcat 7. as on your comment back on the tomcat 7 line in pom file. try to use spring boot version 1.1.10

Comment: @kucing_terbang Thanks for that! I tried it but I got a missing bean error though: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

Now I did a search and found this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796811/webserver-fails-to-start-due-to-missing-bean

But I already have the dependency "spring-boot-starter-web" specified? What am I missing? A version for it?

Comment: @DengkeSha that could be many things, could be because maven central repo failed to get the `spring-boot-starter-web` or could be invalid jar version which cannot work with spring boot version 1.1.10. Is it possible if you update your question and post the stacktrace?

Comment: @kucing_terbang I've update my question now with the stacktrace. Any help interpreting it is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @DengkeSha my mistake, I try to open pom.xml of the spring boot version 1.1.10 and it didn't found. maybe you should try to use version `1.1.12.RELEASE` as suggested by spring boot website.

Comment: @kucing_terbang Thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a go but it still gave me the same issue when I tried to run it. I noticed after I mvn clean I get a compilation error - perhaps this is indicative of a deeper issue? I've updated my post with the stacktraces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to run your code in my local pc and there was an error similar like what happened in your place. And, these are the steps that I did to remove those error.

1. Update the spring boot version

   ```
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
   ```
2. Update your main class as `@SpringBootApplication` annotation only exists after spring boot version 1.2.0

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScan
   public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
               ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

               System.out.println("NinjaSquare server up and running with Spring Boot!");
               System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

               String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
               Arrays.sort(beanNames);
               for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                   System.out.println(beanName);
               }
           }
   }
   ```
3. Remove the "`webapp-runner`" dependency from `pom.xml` as this library also has class `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` which conflicted with the one from embedded tomcat library.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
       <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
       <version>${com.github.jsimone.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Yes, remove those lines ;)
4. Run the application and then, profit ?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @kucing_terbang for your help with this! The server comes up now. As a side note, I discovered that the main issue was due to the conflict with webapp-runner. I was able to use spring-boot-starter-parent with 1.2.3.RELEASE after resolving that conflict.

As a side question, how did you know/where did you look to find the compatible versions of different components of spring? I think it will be useful to know your thinking process so I can resolve similar issues in future! (I'm also having a side issue which may be to do with versions now as well, so it'll be useful). Thanks!

Comment: well, mainly from grepcode.com they provide a good list of source code on many version.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the share. It looks like a very useful resource. Cheers!

Answer (score 28):

I had the exact same issue with `Spring boot` and the `embedded tomcat server`.

### How I fixed it

After many hours of ***hit and trial*, *running and re-running*** I found that ***I had initially added local tomcat server to my project*** which was conflicting with the embedded tomcat server that `Spring Boot` provides. After removing the Tomcat Server from the projects build path running `Spring Boot` was like a charm.

Just right click the project

```
Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Libraries(Tab)
```

and remove your Tomcat server runtime if you have added one by mistake. You should be good to go now.

Comment: Same for me. In Eclipse I went to `Window > Prefences > Server > Runtime Environment` and deleted the Tomcat 7 environment I previously added. After removing I was able to run a `@SpringBootApplication` from within another `.jar` file.

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahKhan. This answer saved my day.

Comment: @SudheerKumar I am glad i could help brother.

Comment: @DaiKaixian For the reason that in the new workspace you have not yet added the server to your build path!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error happen to me because I created a Maven project using the webapp archetype.

Recreating the project as a simple Maven project solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error because I copied some jar files from tomcat's lib folder to jdk's lib folder.So it have an incompatible version of Tomcat on the classpath. I solved this issue after reinstalling jdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had my error solved by changing the Apache Tomcat Version 9 to Version 8.5 that was not supported by Spring Boot 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Update the spring boot version

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when i tried to use an inhouse library which was built with a higher version of Springboot 2.2.x, whereas my code was using 2.1.x. I had upgraded to 2.2.x and the problem vanished. Ideally this happens when there are two versions of tomcat libraries in your classpath, you have find out the needed springboot version and upgrade/downgrade to fix the exception.