# web application with org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter error

Tags: web-applications, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have copied a web application from springtoolsguide site i.e. form validation app. I have the pom and source files exactly as they have it but when trying to run the application I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.effyis.vqsense.Application.main
(Application.java:15)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.
 setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
 at  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.
 SkipPatternJarScanner$Tomcat8TldSkipSetter.setSkipPattern
(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.
   setPatternToTomcat8SkipFilter(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.
  SkipPatternJarScanner.<init>(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:56)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.
  apply(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext
(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer
(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:154)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.
createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.
 onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 7 more
```

This is really annoying. I think it is related to how the servers are set up, including tomcat, pivotal tc, or VMWare vFabric since if I try to run it on those it gives completely different error. This is a springboot application and just wanted to run it in a browser like chrome.

Tried other posts suggestions but this did not work. [soln post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444650/spring-boot-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-tomcat-util-scan-stan)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use an incompatible version of Tomcat. Can you share your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: I can't recall all steps as it has been a few days but resolved errors by copying logging folder to a new location. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

You have an old and incompatible version of Tomcat on the classpath. This is the solution: [Spring Boot exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157970/spring-boot-exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-standardjarscanner-setjarsca)