# spring boot execution: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;V

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and trying to start with a simple project in spring boot, But unable to start the project as Java application and receiving the error message mentioned below,

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCWou.png)

SpringBootWebApplication.java

```
package main.java.com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
package main.java.com.test;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Access the bootstrap Css like this, 
        Spring boot will handle the resource mapping automcatically -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- 
    <spring:url value="/css/main.css" var="springCss" />
    <link href="${springCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
     -->
    <c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
    <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spring Boot</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</h1>
            <h2>Message: ${message}</h2>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Below are the list of Jar's i have added under /WEB-INF/lib

[Jar's Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWUav.png)

Receiving the error message when running the project as java application

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

Jun 18, 2018 2:52:41 PM main.java.com.mykong.SpringBootWebApplication logStarting
INFO: Starting SpringBootWebApplication on BR-LL58000 with PID 9864 (C:\Users\tpucchin\workspace\SpringHelloWorld\build\classes started by TPUCChin in C:\Users\tpucchin\workspace\SpringHelloWorld)
Jun 18, 2018 2:52:41 PM main.java.com.mykong.SpringBootWebApplication logStartupProfileInfo
INFO: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Jun 18, 2018 2:52:41 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@81db25: startup date [Mon Jun 18 14:52:41 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 18, 2018 2:52:42 PM org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
Jun 18, 2018 2:52:42 PM org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication reportFailure
SEVERE: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at main.java.com.mykong.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter(Lorg/apache/tomcat/JarScanFilter;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner$Tomcat8TldSkipSetter.setSkipPattern(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.setPatternToTomcat8SkipFilter(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.<init>(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.apply(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 8 more
```

What i am doing wrong here and how to resolve this error?. I have tried the answers avaiable in the previous queries but unable to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.setJarScanFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444650/spring-boot-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-tomcat-util-scan-stan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue was caused by the tomcat server which i configured for this project, I removed the server from the project and now able to run the project as java application without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties -> project facet --> uncheck tomcat from runtime.